# Programmatic skins in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am having 2 problems creating programmatic skin for Canvas.

First problem:
I would like to have background with rounded corners and I am using GraphicsUtil.drawRoundRectComplex in order to have round corners for only the upper two corners. The problem is that drawRoundRectComplex takes for each corner one single parameter - the corner radius. However my scaleX and scaleY factors are different and in fact the corners are not properly rounded because I either can set the radius using scaleX or scaleY.
Graphics.drawRoundRect is better because it takes two parameters for the corners - elipse width and height and then you could apply both scale factors but it doesn't allow me to specify different radius for different corners.
I am looking for an idea how to use GraphicsUtil.drawRoundRectComplex when scaleX and scaleY are different.

Second problem:
Even though I set my programmatic skin through style - <> the skin's updateDisplayList gets executed only once and after that somehow "backgroundImage" style gets "undefined" and my programmatic skin is not associated anymore to the Canvas instance. As a workaround I am setting on each resize event "backgroundImage" style again but this is ugly.
What could cause such "silent" resetting of the "backgroundImage" style to undefined?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

isnt the backgroundImage supported by the RectangularBorder Class?

[Rectabgular Border at Adobe AS3 Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/skins/RectangularBorder.html)